# How can I list every file with a specific extension except one with bash

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I have a directory with multiple files of different types (eg. pdf, txt, etc).  Let's say I want to select every file of type .example except for one how would I go about doing so?  Let's say the files are all called ex_.example, where the _ is a number between 0 and 30.

I tried ls ex*[^12]*.example; I got every example file besides 1, 2, 11, 12, 21, and 22.  I don't understand how I could get every single file besides JUST file number 12.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extended globbing. Quoting [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html):

> `!(pattern-list)`
>
> Matches anything except one of the given
>   patterns.

```
shopt -s extglob               # enables extended globbing
ls -l ex!(12).example          # for more numbers, you can use !(12|18|...)
```

Comment: Turns out I am just dumb.  My files are not ACTUALLY called example.  Oh well.  This worked, thank you!  Also, I am still curious as to what shopt -s extglob  does

Comment: @Darokrithia As you can see in the code, it enables feature called extended globbing. It allows you to use more complex globbing constructs. Refer to the link in my answer for detailed information.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the link.  Seems like it is one of those days :\  My question was more on what extended globbing actually is.  Anyway I will read the link

Answer (score 1):

I like `find` for this:

```
find . -name *.example # print every file with the .example extension seen from the current directory
find . -name *.example ! -name ex12.example # all but ex12.example
```

Note that `find` will recursively search all directories starting at the specified directory.  Use the `-maxdepth` switch to control this if needed.

Comment: If I wanted to use this in a command/script would I have to pipe it?  I was more looking for a general method of accessing files so I can hand them to a script.  If piping is the only way, that is okay

Comment: @Darokrithia There are many things you can do with the output of `find`.  Yes, you can pipe the output.  You can also capture the output in a bash variable and do string manipulation.  Some "commands" can also be passed directly to `find`.